# How to get the list of the first column value from wikipedia table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I am trying to get the list of years in the first column of the first wikipedia [table here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wars_1000%E2%80%931499#1000.E2.80.931099) (Start) and place it inside a select

I am reading the json this way but i cannot grab what I need in order to place it in a select:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&prop=text&section=1&page=List_of_wars_1000%E2%80%931499&callback=?",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

            var markup = data.parse.text["td"];
            var i = $('<div></div>').html(markup);

            // remove links as they will not work
            i.find('a').each(function() { $(this).replaceWith($(this).html()); });

            // remove any references
            i.find('sup').remove();

            // remove cite error
            i.find('.mw-ext-cite-error').remove();

            $('#article').html($(i).find('p'));         
        },
        error: function (errorMessage) {
        }
    });    

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution for your:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&prop=text&section=1&page=List_of_wars_1000%E2%80%931499&callback=?",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
          var html = data.parse.text['*'];

          if(!html) {
            return;
          }

          var $hiddenContent = $('<div/>').html(data.parse.text['*']).hide();
          var $firstColumnCells = $hiddenContent.find('table.wikitable').find('td:first-child');
          $hiddenContent.remove(); // remove our helper div

          var values = [];
          $firstColumnCells.each(function(idx, cell) {
            
            var val = $(cell).text().match(/\d+/)[0];
            
            values.push($(cell).text());
            // you can also do something here with the value
            $('#article').append('<div>'+ val + '</div>');
          });

          // show as array in your console if you like or doSomething with the array
          //console.log(values);       
        },
        error: function (errorMessage) {
        }
    });    

});
```

```css
#article div {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  background: grey;
  width: auto;
  color: white;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="article">
  <h2>Years</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, any way we can remove the string in the year 1083?

Answer (score 0):

The result from your url is an object with name "*" not "td", so your line:

```
data.parse.text["td"]
```

becomes

```
data.parse.text["*"]
```

this gives you all of the markup of the article, which you already parse into html.  There may be other urls you can use, but this is the result of the one provided.

You can then use jquery to find what you want from that article, eg:

```
html.find("table td:first-child")
```

to get all the first columns from the table (you might want `table:first` for other articles etc).

Working snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&prop=text&section=1&page=List_of_wars_1000%E2%80%931499&callback=?",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

            var markup = data.parse.text["*"];
            var html = $('<div/>').html(markup);
          
            var cells = html.find("table td:first-child");
            cells.each(function() {
                console.log($(this).text());
              });
          
            var years = cells.map(function() { return $(this).text(); }).get();
            console.log(years.join(","))
          
        },
        error: function (errorMessage) {
        }
    });    

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, any way we can remove the string in the year 1083?

Comment: Possibly use parseint() or a regex

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be going for wrong property `td` in the response object

Try

```
 var markup = data.parse.text['*'];
 var i = $('<div></div>').html(markup);
 var years = i.find('table:first tr:gt(1)').map(function() {
   return $(this).children().eq(0).text()
 }).get()
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/7hxcyn9r/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

you can do that very easily by selecting the `td:first-child` of all the `tr`. And if its another field, you can use the `td:nth-child(5)` pseudo selector.

here an example with pure javascript (tested);

```
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll(".wikitable tr td:first-child")
var values = Array.prototype.map.call(nodes, function(n){
    return n.innerContent;
})
```

similar in jQuery, you can do (untested);

```
var values = $(".wikitable tr td:first-child").each(function(n){
    return n.innerContent;
})
```

you later can use the `wrap` function of jQuery to make each text/year an option element which you can pass to a select dropdown